# Python3: How can I create instances dynamically in the __init__ function

Tags: python-3.x

An answer to this question must exist somewhere but unfortunately I lack the proper vocabulary and terms to find it.
Here is my problem:

I'm creating a multiple choice questions test, and it is made of **slides**. Each Slide contains one *or more* **Questions** so for instance I could have these two different slides:

[The two slides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcwT8.png)

Associated to these slides is a code that will record the slides details, such as questions answer, number of questions, etc...
So for each slide my code creates an instance of the class **Slide**.
What I need to do is to create the appropriate number of instances of the class **Question** for each slide:

- slide 1 -> one Question instance
- slide 2 -> three Question instances

I need to create them dynamically, and also to access them dynamically. How can I do or is it even possible?

Comment: Huh? Append to a list inside a for loop, creating a new `Question(...)` instance each time (or use a list comprehension for convenience/compactness)?

Comment: You may want to add some code of you're trying to do, because it's rather unclear.

Comment: It depends also on how you know what should be created, and how it should be initialized. Also, you should describe it better. It is not clear whether your decision to create a class for everything is the best one. It depends on situation.

Answer (score 1):

That is simply a matter of having an attribute associated to your slide instances where you store a reference to how many Quations you wish.

The attribute can be a list, or a dictionary. Supposing the slide gets as parameter a "config" which is a list, each element containing the proper parameters to create a Question instance:

```
class Question:
   ...

class Slide:
    def __init__(self, config):
         self.questions = []
         for parameters in config:
              self.questions.append(Question(**parameters))
```

You can then either access directly the `slide.questions` attribute, or put some utility functions that will take the question number as an argument.

Answer (score -1):

it works! thank you for your help and sorry for not posting any code before: I was stuck.

```
class Question:

    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key


class Slide:

    def __init__(self, info):
        self.number_of_questions = info[0]
        self.keys = info[1:len(info)]

        # create questions list
        self.questions = []

        for i in range(self.number_of_questions):
            self.questions.append(Question(self.keys[i]))
```

now when I'm testing:

```
info1 = [1, "a"]
slide1 = Slide(info1) 
print(slide1.questions[0].key)

info2 = [3, "a","b","c"]
slide2 = Slide(info2)  
print(slide2.questions[1].key)
```

In the kernel I get exactly the following outputs which is what I wanted:

```
>>a
>>b
```

Comment: `info[1:len(info)]` no need for that in Python. Just leave the argument after `:` blank, like in:  ` info[1:]` . The "end of the sequence" is implicit.